# Wordpress, как подключить файл из другого плагина?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть два плагина WordPress. Например:

- `parent`
- `child`

Плагину `child` необходимо подключить файл из `parent`, чтобы не дублировать код. Как узнать до него путь?

Подключил так:

```php
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/patent/utils/hash.php');
```

Но это "хардкод". Как это решить?

Comment: Подключаются не файлы, а функции.

Comment: Никакого хардкода тут нет, все нормально. Слаг плагина (parent) - величина постоянная, не меняется никогда.